# Speeding up maven clean

Tags: maven, maven-2, settings, maven-3, profile

The following advice appears to be for maven 1.x.

http://bosy.dailydev.org/2009/02/speed-up-your-maven-build-four-times.html

How can a 'qclean' profile as described above (or equivalent) be defined in maven 3.x  settings.xml ?

Comment: Why do you need that? What's the problem with mvn clean ?

Comment: Deletion of folders on Windows operating systems has terrible performance, in a large multi-module maven project this can take minutes

Comment: Than you have other problems than Maven. This is often caused by problems with virus scanners, some other task or other tools...Not by Maven. BTW: How large is your project?

Comment: @wytten The the obvious solution would be to switch to a sane operating system :) Otherwise, I don't see why the linked solution would not work in a maven 3 project.

Comment: I didn't mean to imply that maven had a problem, and I would use a different OS if I could.  But maven 3.x doesn't appear to allow <build> inside <profile> settings, and I don't want to hack the poms.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `build` element can only be specified in a profile of your project, not globally in the settings.xml. This is explained in the [maven settings reference](http://maven.apache.org/settings.html#Profiles):

> The `profile` element in the settings.xml is a truncated version of the pom.xml `profile` element. It consists of the `activation`, `repositories`, `pluginRepositories` and `properties` elements.
>
> The `profile` elements only include these four elements because they concerns themselves with the build system as a whole (which is the role of the settings.xml file), not about individual project object model settings.

The linked article does not mention the settings.xml or maven 1 as far as I can see. As the article is from 2009 I guess the workaround was implemented for maven 2 and included in the projects pom.